# How can I use an Elastic Search managed service securely from Azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, elasticsearch

I've built an app that collects data from RSS feeds using Azure Functions and Azure Table Storage and I want to index the data in Elastic Search using a managed service.

There isn't a managed solution in the Azure ecosystem so I am wondering what my options are.

> If I used the [Elastic Search Service](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service) or [AWS Elastic Search Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) how can I index or query them securely from an Azure function?

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from using AWS Elasticsearch from anywhere. It should just work.

Comment: Sure I can use it, but how can I use it securely? My understanding is that I would have to have the endpoint as public access. If I have public access how can I restrict access to only my Azure functions?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-python or https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/